# bash readline bind with dynamic prefix argument?

Tags: bash, readline, key-bindings

Is there a way to make a bash keybinding that moves the cursor N characters forward, where N is variable? I was hoping I could do

```
bind '"\e\C-i": "\e$(echo "$N")\C-f"'
```

but of course the `$()` isn't expanded beforehand.

Note that I don't want to have to specify the prefix manually – I want a function to give it (or if it's read from an env-var or a file as a workaround).

Comment: Use `Alt+5` `Control+f` to move 5 characters forward.

Comment: Use 2 questions to ask two questions.

Comment: @choroba, clarified it a bit now (I don't want to count N myself); second question is now at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149518/pre-fill-bash-readline-incremental-search-query