# pre-fill bash/readline incremental search query?

Tags: bash, readline, key-bindings

Can I, with bash `bind`, hand a string given by some function to pre-fill a `\C-s` query?  I was hoping I could do

```
bind '"\e\C-i": "\C-s$(echo "$FOO")\C-j"'
```

but that just searches for the exact (unexpanded) `$(echo "$FOO")`.

Answer (score 1):

`readline` doesn't support evaluating shell expressions in macros, but there is a workaround. Introduce two auxiliary key sequence bindings such that

1. The first one performs a forward search history operation with a fixed query string.
2. The second one configures the first one, by setting the said fixed query string to the value of a bash variable or the output of some bash function.

Your desired key sequence must call 2 followed by 1.

The following is an actual implementation of the above idea, using auxiliary key sequences `"\e\C-o"` and `"\e\C-p"` (if you are using those for other purposes, don't forget to replace them with unused key sequences):

```
$ setup_fixedfwdsearchhistory_binding() { bind '"\e\C-o":"\C-s'"$FOO"'\C-j"'; }
$ bind -x '"\e\C-p": setup_fixedfwdsearchhistory_binding'
$ bind '"\e\C-i": "\e\C-p\e\C-o"'
```